# Get Link from variable on php

Tags: php, socialengine

I have a variable within Social Engine 4 that I want to show the text result it comes up with

```
$avatar = $this->itemPhoto($this->viewer(), 'thumb.icon');
```

the variable $avatar contains a link to an image which is stored on the server with a link in the DB.  What I want to see is what the link text it is returning.  Any suggestions

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Give this a go:

```
ob_start();
$this->itemPhoto($this->viewer(), 'thumb.icon');
$avatar = ob_get_clean();

var_dump( $avatar );
```

Comment: Unfortunately what happens is it still shows the image.  Which is why I want to see the raw data it has in it.  I hope that helps make sense.

Comment: yeah, that didn't do it.  Unfortunately I am working within the confines of a CMS that does not like to play nice.  The full story is I want to pass the link to the image to another application.  What seems to be going on is the information is muddled with other crap I cannot figure out.

Comment: Use the code I gave you, and then show us the results of a var_dump($avatar). :)

Comment: This is what I get string(0) ""

Comment: @Matthew Blancarte: Why do you think `$this->itemPhoto` echoes something?

Comment: Okay now try var_dump( $this->itemPhoto($this->viewer(), 'thumb.icon') )

Comment: @Matthew Blancarte: it would return **a link**, as specified in the original question: "*the variable $avatar contains a link*"

Comment: @zerkms OP said when he tries to store the variable, it outputs the image onto the page.

Comment: @zerkms "Unfortunately what happens is it still shows the image." I am going off what OP is telling me. I originally told him to var_dump($avatar) ;)

Comment: @Matthew Blancarte: ok. Now I'm confused too ;-)

Comment: string(111) "" and inside the quotes is the image I want.

Comment: ok explain what you mean show the string... I am not trying to be difficult, however, is looks on the page as string(111)"{IMAGE}"

Comment: Not to worry, you're not being difficult. Okay that doesn't make sense. It should be something like string(111)"<img src='blah.com' />"

Comment: Yeah and that is what I need to see LOL then I need the raw data of the link without the img src

Comment: ok I want to clarify what I need.  When I type $this->itemPhoto($this->viewer(), 'thumb.icon'); it shows the logged in users profile photo.  I need to get the link to that photo, store it in a variable and pass it to another application.  I hope that helps.

Comment: I'm just surprised that the output buffer isn't working... It should have stored it for you, instead of outputting the actual image.